# Remove python - now apt is broke

Tags: apt, package-management, recovery-mode

I am running on Kubuntu 20.04. I uninstalled python3, now system is broken.

When I boot to root recovery mode, I can not run apt update or apt install to fix all the broken packages.

If I run sudo apt update...

```
Temporary failure resolving 'ca.achive.ubuntu'
```

Along with about 10 other instance of errors like this.

Right after I realized my mistake, I reinstalled python. Now that I rebooted it totally borked because of the other packages that are gone.

I know there are lots of questions about how to fix uninstalled python, but this question is about how to fix my broken apt now.

Comment: Many Ubuntu tools use python (`python3` esp. in modern releases), so you lose access to those tools should you remove python.  That includes front-end tools like `apt` (`dpkg` will still work)... Apt is **not** broken, it needs python for it to work; your issue is you removed python....  (Minimum requirement of Ubuntu is `python3-minimal | 3.8.2-0ubuntu2   | focal`; maybe now 3.8.5 but that's what `rmadison` currently tells me)

Comment: I reinstalled python right afterwards and it is now installed. The problem is the packages it uninstall with it have broke the system.

Comment: This is not a duplicate. Sometimes I think the mods here cant read.